# Parsing Date in Java using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: date, simpledateformat

Developing an Application where i have to parse the following date:
2015-02-02T11:21:51.895Z

using SimpleDateFormat class. But I am getting a Date Parsing Exception.
Here is my code snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");`


 Date qdate = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0).getTime();
                    try {
                        qdate = sdf.parse(dt);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {


                    }
```

Comment: What does your `Date Parsing exception` say in it?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your input "2015-02-02T11:21:51.895Z" you should see that your assumed pattern does not match the input because the pattern does not expect the millisecond part but the literal "Z".

Beyond this, the pattern you used is wrong because of following reasons:

```
m = minute
M = month
h = hour of half day (1-12)
H = hour of full day (0-23)
X = timezone designator (because Z is not a literal but stands for UTC+00:00)
```

So you need (please also refer to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)):

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your format (add `.SSS` for the miliseconds):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
Date date = sdf.parse("2015-02-02T11:21:51.895Z");
```

Comment: My problem gets solved when I use the following pattern SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'ssssZ'");